# Illegal Characters in Path only on internal VS-Server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

I got an MVC-Application that creates a parameter using jQuery. In that jQuery method I create a string value that concatinates two GUIDs: s=guid1+'|'+guid2;

the jS looks like this:

```
 $('.editUser').click(function () {
        var userId = $(this).attr("userId") + "|" + $(this).attr("itemprop");

        $("#editUserPopup").html("")
            .dialog("option", "title", "Edit Note")
            .load("./Services/EditUser/" + userId, function () { $("#editUserPopup").dialog("open"); });
        });
```

Inside the controller I got an actionmethod that uses that parameter. The generated URL is like:

```
localhost:57465/Services/EditUser/7d2ee650-fd14-4589-a10e-2030d261d4e7%7C717f91f1-2f38-4e89-ad5d-14621ebdcfcf
```

the code snippet is:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=0) ]
    public ActionResult EditUser( string id)
    {
        string userId = id.Split('|')[0];
            string serviceId = id.Split('|')[1];
...}
```

When I debug this project with the internal Visual Studio Deployment Server from VS I receive the following error:

> [ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]

even before the method is entered. When using IIS Express, no error is thrown.

What could be the problem here? Is there maybe something wrong that the IIS fixed "automatically" but not the internal server?

Comment: Try using a `.` instead of `|`, or at least some other character which does not need to be encoded in the URL.

Comment: Your hint was completely wrong and correct in the same time :) "." Does the opposite: Works on internal server but crashes on IIS. I took "!" instead. Thanks

Comment: Heh, glad you got it sorted.